# Position ''top/bottom'' takes the image out of the div

Tags: css, containers, css-position, padding

This might be a bit more advance, but I cannot get the answer anywhere, and I am starting getting mad.

I manage to position my clouds as I want them in percentages values, so they are in proportion of the viewport/device screen. My div has relative position so the images inside (they all have absolute position) can move inside relative to the wrapping container (the div)

However, if I change or add `top` or `bottom` position percentages values to my image, somehow, the image moves out of the parent div (with `position: relative`), so, if I change the `padding` of my wrapping div (so it can cover more area of the screen), the images are not affected, they do not move along the alterations of the div's padding, as if they were not nested inside my div.

Does anyone know what exactly it is going on?

```
<div class="top-container">
    <img class="top-cloud">
    <h1>I'm Marcos</h1>
    <h2>A Software Developer</h2>
    <img class="bot-cloud">
    <img class="mountain">
</div>
```

This is my CSS

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

h1 {
    margin-top: 0;
}

.top-container {
    background-color: #79bac1;
    position: relative;
    padding: 10% 0 0 0;
}

.top-cloud {
    position: absolute;
    width: 8%;
    left: 15%;
}

.mountain {
    width: 35%;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}

.bot-cloud {
    position: absolute;
    width: 8%;
    right: 15%;
    top: 10% /*If I delete this value, the image (.bot-cloud) moves in and it gets affected by the ".top-container" padding. But if I leave it, and modify the padding in the ".top-container", it gets moved out of the ".top-container" as if it's not wrapped by it.*/
}
```

Comment: Without the images available it is hard to see what happens, but at first glance I'd say your `top-cloud` needs a `top` attribute and your `bot-cloud` a `bottom` attribute instead of `top`. Not sure what the effect will be of `.mountain { margin: auto }`, because it is a sibling of the clouds with the same `z-index` it probably pushes them aside. So, make the images avaialble or give at least their physical width and height values.

Answer (score 0):

You image has `position: absolute;` , which takes it out of the document flow, i.e. it will not occupy any space which wouldn't be there if you just erased it - it only covers space of other elements.

Its only reference in matter of *position* is the next highest *parent* element which has `position: relative`. If `top` is `0`, its top will be directly at the top border of the parent. A `padding` of the parent will not change that at all (see snippet below).

If you use a negative `top` value, it will (vertically) move *outside*  the parent (= up), for example `top: -10%` will place it 10% (of the parent's height) *above* ( = outside) the top border of the parent. A positive value, like `top: 10%` will place it 10% (of the parent's height) *below* ( = inside) the top border of the parent. The reference for `top` is always the top border of the parent element. Same princicple for `left`, `right` and `bottom` values - their  reference will be the left, right and bottom border of the relative parent.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.top-container {
  background-color: #79bac1;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10% 0 0 0;
}

.top-cloud {
  position: absolute;
  width: 8%;
  left: 15%;
}

.mountain {
  width: 35%;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

.bot-cloud {
  position: absolute;
  width: 8%;
  right: 15%;
  top: 0%;/*If I delete this value, the image (.bot-cloud) moves in and it gets affected by the ".top-container" padding. But if I leave it, and modify the padding in the ".top-container", it gets moved out of the ".top-container" as if it's not wrapped by it.*/
}
```

```html
<div class="top-container">
  <img class="top-cloud">
  <h1>I'm Marcos</h1>
  <h2>A Software Developer</h2>
  <img src="https://placehold.it/200x150/d66" class="bot-cloud" >
  <img src="https://placehold.it/150x100/6a9" class="mountain">
</div>
```